# Get value from Databse and outprint if or else statement based on selection from ComboBox

Tags: java, sqlite, combobox

DB information
DB name is contact 
Row is Answer which is a bool in sqlite

Values in row are 0 or 1
0 for false and 1 for true

combobox name is answerCall

textfield name is `textACall`

upon selection of the `JCombobox` I want to

```
  System.out.println ("Do Not Answer!");
```

or

```
System.out.println("Answer Call!");
```

Into the `textfield`

As of right now it is only printing to the `console` not the `textfield` 
and it only prints out Answer Call! no matter what the selection of the Combobox is.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me correct this.

```
private void answerCallActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    
   String ans= (String) answerCall.getSelectedItem();
   try {
     String sql = "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE Answer='"+ans+"'";
     pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     rs = pst.executeQuery();

     if (ans.equals("1")) {
       textACall.setText(ans);
       System.out.println ("Do Not Answer!");
     } else {
       System.out.println("Answer Call!");
     }
   } catch(Exception e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that ans is not what you think it is. I would place a System.out.println("'" + ans + "'"); line before your if statement.

Comment: ok ya your right it didn't print anything. so where am i going wrong here? i need the value from DB contact at row answer based on the selection of the name in the combobox.

Comment: @NichoDiaz Thanks. Please accept my answer. If you need values from the database, you need to be getting them from the result set. You're using the selected item from the selection box. You should probably start a new question if you still need help.